Installing Allure.Specflow causes my Specflow binding to become ambiguous
So before installing the Allure.SpecFlowPlugin all my bindings are fine.
However, when I do install the plugin I am getting binding ambiguity on ALL of my steps.

These F12 to the exact same binding step definition.
So when I try and run a test I get
System.InvalidOperationException : No fixture, test, or step context is active.
TearDown : System.InvalidOperationException : No test context is active.

Versions I have installed are:
<PackageReference Include="Allure.SpecFlow" Version="2.12.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.9.74" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Autofac" Version="3.9.74" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit" Version="3.9.74" />
<PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.14.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.74" />

I have tried different version combinations. Its like it is duplicating my bindings.
I have in my specflow.json file
{
  "bindingCulture": {
    "language": "en-us"
  },
  "language": {
    "feature": "en-us"
  },
  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "Allure.SpecFlowPlugin"
    }
  ]
}

It should include the project bindings by default. So this looks correct.
All the internet brings back is find the duplicate and remove. So I am lost at what to check next?

Whenever I run into something truly weird (and this question fits the "truly weird" category) I always delete all files from the bin and obj folders in my solution, plus delete the .vs folder at the root of the visual studio solution. If you are using Git, commit any pending changes,  and then run git clean -fdx from the command line to "super clean" your solution -- important: this deletes all untracked files, so be sure to commit anything you want to keep!
